# SKScene iPad height width reversed

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to fill my SKScene with tiles, in an iPad app that only supports landscape mode.  Within the scene I detect h & w as such:

```
int h = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
int w = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```

Unfortunately, the dimensions sent back are the reverse of what they need to be.  There are lots of topics in SO discussion this problem within the content of a view controller or a view, and the solution seems to be to detect screen size in viewWillAppear, not in viewDidLoad.  This does not seem to be a valid solution for SKScenes, however.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try, not using `viewDidLoad` and use this

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for testing the view's scene not being nil - most solutions I've seen don't consider the fact that viewWillLayoutSubviews may be called repeatedly, ie when the view size or visibility changes

Comment: Do you mean don't use viewDidLoad in the viewController?  In which file should I implement viewWillLayoutSubviews? The SKScene, the ViewController, or somewhere else?

Comment: In the ViewController, you'll see a method which contains essentially the same contents as above, but its it ViewDidLoad, remove that, and all the above method.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be behaving at least differently. But when I do this:  
    int h = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    int w = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    
in the scene, I get the incorrect dimensions. When one is within the scene, how does one get the correct height and width for landscape mode?

Comment: use self.frame, there you can access what you need, ie self.frame.size.height

Comment: Funny you suggest that.  The reason I avoided using frame all along and always tried to used bounds was due to all the related discussions which seemed to suggest bounds was a more reliable determiner of height and width than frame.  But I guess for that to be true requires special circumstances.

Answer (score 11):

It doesn't make sense to *initialize* the scene in the layout handler. *Resize* the scene in the layout handler. (That's what it's for.)

```
@implementation SGOMyScene
{
    SKScene *scene;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    scene = [SGOMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    SKView *skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size;
}
```

Your scene should implement `- (void)didChangeSize:(CGSize)oldSize` to move everything into the right place.

Hooray, now your game handles device rotations too.

Comment: Wish I could vote for this several times. Whilst the viewWillLayoutSubviews technique, seen above and in various books, works to some extent if you log the actual width and height of the scene they never change from the initial setting. Whereas the above takes care of initialisation and change.

Comment: Also viewWillLayoutSubviews is also called everytime the devices rotates, which is a pain