# bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect not working in landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm just trying to set up a basic scene in landscape, with gravity, and having the scene in an edge loop.

I set up the scene's physics body and the mainCharacter sprite physics body, here is my code:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor redColor];
        [self setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:[self frame]]];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)setupMain
{
    if (!self.mainCharacter)
    {
        self.mainCharacter = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"spriteDefault"];

       [self.mainCharacter setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([self frame]), CGRectGetMidY([self frame]))];

       [self addChild:self.mainCharacter];

       self.mainCharacter.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.mainCharacter.frame.size];
       self.mainCharacter.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
       self.mainCharacter.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
       self.mainCharacter.physicsBody.mass = 0.02;
    }
 }
```

So, in portrait mode, everything works perfectly, however, in landscape, things get really screwy.

I figured it has something to do with

```
  [self setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:[self frame]]];
```

Oddly enough, the edge loop for the x axis for landscape (the y axis in portrait mode) works fine, but I just fall through the y axis (x for portrait).

My guess is that the frame is returning the position on the y axis somewhere not within the bounds of the screen in landscape mode.... meaning its somewhere above or below the screen. 
...Maybe... Not really sure.

However, I have tried several different options, including manually setting the rectangle myself by using 
    CGRectMake()
I wasn't able to get anything to work properly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353942/skscene-ipad-height-width-reversed/19354725#19354725

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a super Janky fix...

```
 self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 200)];
```

I'm not sure why this works... and it's obviously going to have some problems on smaller screen sizes... better fixes and explanations would be much appreciated!! 
Thanks :D

Comment: see Smick's comment for the actual solution

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup the edge loop in the viewWillLayoutSubviews, since the scene size is only known at then:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
if (!skView.scene) {
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the collisionBitMask of your mainCharacter equals to the sceneCategory (need to create). Your nodes will only be affected if you tell them.