# SKSpriteNode Positioning (Or Xcode iOS Simulator)

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, sprite-kit

I have a png file with size 568*320. And a SKSpriteNode is created using spriteNodeWithImageNamed. The SKSpriteNode is used as a background in the game. I supposed the background fits in iPhone 5 screen perfectly. However, in Xcode 5.1 iOS Simulator with iPhone Retina (4-inch) only part of the image shows up to zoom in to fit the screen. Below shows how the node is positioned. Can anyone advise?

**[added] I now suspect it is device orientation. In this case it is landscape. Still need a solution.**

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    _backgroundNode = [BackgroundNode loadFromImage];

    _backgroundNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild: _backgroundNode];
}
return self;
```

}

Comment: have you changed the center of _backgroundNode? show the entire code

Comment: More code was added. This piece of code is pretty much all worth showing. BackgroundNode class is a subclass of SKSPriteNode and all method loadFromImage does is call spriteNodeWithImageNamed

Comment: try to change _backgroundNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);

Comment: Still the same. I now suspect it is device orientation. I used landscape

Comment: How do you present the first scene? If it's in the view controller's viewDidLoad, that'll give you wrong coordinates in landscape. Move it over to viewWillLayoutSubviews and present the scene when self.view.scene is nil. Check SO for examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SKScene iPad height width reversed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353942/skscene-ipad-height-width-reversed)

Comment: Yes LeamCocos2D is right. Thank you!